# Using a text file to lay out a words into a grid form

Tags: python, random, grid

I have a list of 6 words from a text file and would like to open the file to read the list of words as a 3x2 grid, also being able to randomise the order of the words every time the program is run.

**words are:**

```
cat, dog, hamster, frog, snail, snake
```

i want them to display as: (but every time the program is run to do this in a random order)

```
cat    dog     hamster
frog   snail   snake
```

so far all i've managed to do is get a single word from the list of 6 words to appear in a random order using - help would be much appriciated

```
import random

words_file = random.choice(open('words.txt', 'r').readlines())
print words_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another one:

```
>>> import random
>>> with open("words.txt") as f:
...    words = random.sample([x.strip() for x in f], 6)
... 
...
>>> grouped = [words[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
>>> for l in grouped:
...     print "".join("{:<10}".format(x) for x in l)
...     
... 
snake     cat       dog       
snail     frog      hamster
```

First we read the contents of the file and pick six random lines (make sure your lines only contain a single word). Then we group the words into lists of threes and print them using string formatting. The `<10` in the format brackets left-aligns the text and pads each item with 10 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the 6 words, you should try [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
words = randoms.sample(open('words.txt').readlines(), 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)!

```
import random

with open('words.txt','r') as infile:
    words_file = infile.readlines()

random.shuffle(words_file) # mix up the words

maxlen = len(max(words_file, key=lambda x: len(x)))+1
print_format = "{}{}{}".format("{:",maxlen,"}")

print(*(print_format.format(word) for word in words_file[:3])
print(*(print_format.format(word) for word in words_file[3:])
```

There are better ways to run through your list grouping by threes, but this works for your limited test case. [Here's a link to some more information on chunking lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python?rq=1)

My favorite recipe is chunking with `zip` and `iter`:

```
def get_chunks(iterable,chunksize):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*chunksize)

for chunk in get_chunks(words_file):
    print(*(print_format.format(word) for word in chunk))
```

Comment: @SteinarLima Gah thanks! I labored over that but didn't have time to check. Fixed